Error Loading Asset Image But Image Is Available
I have an image folder called images on the lib folder (lib/images/logo.png) but when I tried inserting the image on my flutter page I keep getting this error message:
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "lib/images/logo.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#c350c(), name: "lib/images/logo.png",
scale: 1)

Here is the code:
 Image.asset(
   'lib/images/logo.png',
    width: 180,
 ),

I have carefully checked the images folder to be double sure the image is there and it is there. What could be the reason for this error.

have you added it to your pubspec.yaml?

I have been able to fix it by running flutter clean and flutter pub get and it showed.
But I don't know which among both command got it to work

Check if it is correctly added in your pub spec.yaml file ,try to restart your editor.

I have been able to fix it by running flutter clean and flutter pub get. But I don't know which among both command got it to work.

I would close the question in that case. Probably Flutter clean was the important one as it will make flutter rebuild everything on the next build
